# Combining identical subjects in DBpedia SPARQL query

Tags: php, rdf, sparql, dbpedia, triples

I am using the following SPARQL query from PHP where `$title` is the same for all five query triples:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
    { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/$title> rdfs:label ?pageTitle . }
    UNION
    { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/$title> owl:sameAs ?sameAs . }
    UNION
    { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/$title> dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract . }
    UNION
    { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/$title> dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail . }
    UNION
    { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/$title> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiID . }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this so that `$title` is only specified once in the query? I am thinking an anonymous node might be involved, somewhere? perhaps? :-)

Comment: Is there a reason you want a union here, specifically?  It seems like your results will be a table with five columns (one for each variable), but in each row, exactly one of those columns will have a value.  Would you prefer a solution with two columns:  one indicating the property, and one indicating the value?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You're right, in that with the HTML output from http://dbpedia.org/sparql (using a web browser) you get what you describe, but the JSON output gives me something less useless :o) Is there a way to get the output as you describe without doing those union things (e.g. the answer from jimkont - which I am just about to try)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/$title> ?p ?o . 
FILTER (?p IN (rdfs:label, owl:sameAs, dbpedia-owl:abstract, dbpedia-owl:thumbnail, dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID))
```

Instead of `FILTER (?x IN ())` you can also use `VALUES (?x) {<...>, <...> }` as mentioned in another reply

Comment: I accepted this answer as it gets rid of those ugly `UNION`s

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  { ?id rdfs:label ?pageTitle . }
  UNION
  { ?id owl:sameAs ?sameAs . }
  UNION
  { ?id dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract . }
  UNION
  { ?id dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail . }
  UNION
  { ?id dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiID . }
} values (?id) { (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/$title>) }
```

This is a very nice SPARQL 1.1 feature.